# How to downgrade Samsung Galaxy Mini S5570 from 2.3.6 to 2.2.2?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I need help with downgrading my Samsung Galaxy Mini (S5570) from 2.3.6 to 2.2.2.

Answer (score -1):

You can search and download "Samsung S5770 Android 2.2.2 firmware" in google or forum.xda-developer.com in Samsung S5770 section, you can get official ROM and Custom ROM there, then flash it via ODIN (if official) or via custom recovery if Custom ROM

Comment: It looks like the OP isn't well versed in Android's tools. It would help if you could expand your answer with links to the ROMs, and instructions for flashing them.